# The algorithm has some defects that cannot pass all OJ tests which named "partly calculate A add B"

Tags: c, algorithm

The OJ question is:

> **Question**: Give three positive integer like `A Da B Db` and calculate `Pa+Pb`. And the rule likes
>   *Example: A = 3862767, Da = 6,so Pa = 66*, because there are two number "6" in integer A.
>
> **Input Format**: Enter `A Da B Db`  in one line, and use space to split them, and 0<A,B<10^10
>
> **Output Format**: Show the value of `Pa+Pb` in one line
>
> **Input Example 1**: 3862767 6 13530293 3
>
> **Output Example 1**: 399
>
> **Input Example 2**: 3862767 1 13530293 8
>
> **Output Example 2**: 0

**My Question**: I have passed four of five tests, but have no idea about the reason why my code cannot pass all and the compiler is gcc 4.7.2

and my code is:

```
int fun(int a, int b) {
    int n = 0;
    short i = 1,k;
    do {
        k = a % 10;
        if (k == b) {
            n += i*k;
            i *= 10;
        }
    } while ((a /= 10) != 0);
    return n;
}

int main() {
    int a1, a2, a3, a4;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a1, &a2, &a3, &a4);
    printf("%d", fun(a1, a2) + fun(a3, a4));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you try this
while ((a /= 10) != 0 || a != b);

Comment: or try something like this
   tmp = a;
    do {
        k = tmp % 10;
        if (k == b) {
            n += i*k;
            i *= 10;
        }
        tmp = a/10;
        a = tmp;
    } while (tmp != 0 || tmp == b);

Comment: it seems working file can you pass all 5 test.

Comment: `int` can't represent 10^10-1.

Answer (score 0):

yes, I shouldn't use `short` and `int`, after change to `long long` the tests have passed.@david-eisenstat